# Get Axis relative to rotation Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position, photon

I am currently working on a "Fighting" style game in Unity and Photon. However, I have ran into a small problem that I have no idea how to solve.

The game is 1v1 so there is no more than two players in the room at one time. I have a billboard effect with the healthbar and popup damage text. For example, when the player rotates the camera the enemies text/healthbar will rotate to look at the camera.

The problem is with the damage text. It works to the point that when the enemy is hit the correct number appears and it faces the right direction, however, I would like to add a random variable in the spawn position so it doesn't spawn at the same place. What happens is the axis changes based on the direction the object is facing (looking at player). So in other words if I want a randomize x axis it would change to y and z depending on the rotation of the object.

Here are some pictures to help describe:
[image]

Problem: 
[image]

This is the code I'm using it is attached to the character:

```
void ShowFloatingText(int amt)
{
    Transform c = transform.Find("DamageSpawn").transform;
    GameObject go = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("DamageText", transform.position, Quaternion.identity, 0, null);
    go.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
    go.transform.localPosition = c.localPosition;
    go.transform.localPosition += new Vector3(Random.Range(-randomizeInt.x, randomizeInt.x), Random.Range(-randomizeInt.y/2, randomizeInt.y/2), 0);

    go.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = amt.ToString();
}
```

This is attached to the damageText object and controls rotation:

```
 public void GetCamera()
 {
    GameObject[] g = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    foreach (GameObject gg in g)
    { 
        if (gg.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("isSelf"))
        {
            cam = gg.transform.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").GetComponent<Camera>();


        }
    }

}
private void Start()
{
    Destroy(gameObject, 1.5f);
    //transform.position += offset;
    GetCamera();

}
void Update()
{
    if (cam == null) 
    {
        GetCamera();
    }
    else
    {
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + cam.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward, cam.transform.rotation * Vector3.up);
    }

}
```

I would appreciate and help solving this.
Thank you

Comment: Directly changing it along the x-axis would just affect its x-axis in world space. I suggest using transform.right instead to get the correct vector with which to transform as it will take into account the rotation of the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
void ShowFloatingText(int amt)
{
    Transform c = transform.Find("DamageSpawn").transform;
    GameObject go = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("DamageText", transform.position, Quaternion.identity, 0, null);
    go.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
    go.transform.localPosition = c.localPosition;
    go.transform.localPosition += go.transform.right * Random.Range(-randomizeInt.x/2, randomizeInt.x/2);
    go.transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, Random.Range(-randomizeInt.y/2, randomizeInt.y/2), 0);

    go.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = amt.ToString();
}
```

This takes into account the rotation of the transform and translates along *that* vector instead of simply moving the gameobject along the worldspace x-axis, assuming that Random.Range() returns an `int`.

Comment: I'm not at home right now (the app), However, I'm on my way to test it. I'll let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to fairly new to stack overflow. Thanks for letting me know